# Is an op amp voltage follower better than one made with discrete (MOS)FETs?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, fet, emitter-follower

Is there any advantage of the following op amp based voltage follower:-

[image: opamp]

over one made with discrete MOSFET components such as:-

[image: discretes]

other than component count?

Comment: Homework?  What's the output impedance of the op-amp circuit?  What's the output impedance of the FET circuit?  What's the offset voltage of the opamp circuit?  What's the offset voltage of the FET circuit?

Comment: @TimWescott No Tim.  It's a generic question constructed to draw out an experienced answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes opamps are better. the opamp is two components: the opamp and the bypass capacitor.
the mosfet follower is 5 components.

Additionally, opamps have lower offset voltages and better linearity, and better accuracy because of large amounts of negative feedback.

The only case where I would use a discrete follower would be with high voltages. Because it is more difficult to get high-voltage opamps that are cheap.

Comment: There is technically negative feedback in discrete version.

Comment: Indeed it has. But very much less than the opamp.

Comment: Voltage: Is this why the discrete totem pole configuration is used as an oscilloscope input stage?

Comment: P.S The op amp circuit is shown as dual rail, and often you'd have a larger and smaller bypasser on each rail. That's 5 components too...

Comment: Bypass: there are no bypass caps drawn for the buffer, so that would be 7 components with one bypass cap per rail.

Comment: One last point I did not think about at the time of answering, is that for very fast circuits, it might be significantly cheaper to do a discrete version. This of course costs accuracy in terms of offset, gain and linearity.